# Maven SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: java, maven

I am getting following runtime Exception while running my java code. Could someone please help me resolve the binding conflicts.

```
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Air/Desktop/sms/slf4j-1.7.7/slf4j-android-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Air/Desktop/sms/slf4j-1.7.7/slf4j-jcl-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Air/Desktop/sms/slf4j-1.7.7/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Air/Desktop/sms/slf4j-1.7.7/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Air/Desktop/sms/slf4j-1.7.7/slf4j-nop-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Air/Desktop/sms/slf4j-1.7.7/slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal error in constructor!
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Did you follow installation instructions for slf4j?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Run `mvn dependency:tree` and search which dependency have the `slf4j` implementations you do not want, then *exclude* them with a dependency exclusion like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.someexternallib</groupId>
    <artifactId>someexternallibartifact</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>

    <exclusions>
       <exclusion> 
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion> 
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: This question is all over stack-overflow, but this was finally the thing I needed!

Comment: How to exclude binding at run-time when binding is coming from external classpath?

Comment: You want it in at compile-time, but excluded at runtime?

Comment: Anyone using IntelliJ, you can use the "Maven" window view to see what are the dependencies that are including log4j and slf4j. Found it quite useful.

Comment: Worked very well for me in the same scenarios

Comment: For gradle you run: gradle dependencies

Comment: @houcros where to find the Maven window?

Comment: @P5Coder In IntelliJ: View -> Tool windows -> Maven projects.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you have several implementation of SLF4J; you should exclude all the not necessary ones

Answer (score 5):

This error means that you have multiple implementations of SLF4J in your classpath.
Look for what the errors are specifically saying. i.e :
`SLf4J: Found binding in.....` (This will print all the jar files where it found instances of StaticLoggerBinder.class). Eliminate all such jars from your classpath, except the jar whose StaticLoggerBinder.class implementation you need.

Comment: you are a saviour :)

Answer (score 2):

You can go to POM.xml , open Dependency Hierarchy and find slf4j entries.Except one exclude rest of them by right clicking "exclude maven artifact"

Comment: In which IDE can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This Works !! Update the porm.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.someexternallib</groupId>
<artifactId>someexternallibartifact</artifactId>
<version>...</version>

<exclusions>
   <exclusion> 
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
   <exclusion> 
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```