# Hbase commands not working

Tags: hbase

I am new to Hbase. I have installed it and while running hbase commands I get the following error;

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/hbase-0.98.5-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
ERROR: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping

Here is some help for this command:
List all tables in hbase. Optional regular expression parameter could
be used to filter the output.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when multiple bindings for slf4j are found in the class path and it appears to be a build-time problem. See the referenced http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings on how to deal with it. Similar questions were asked a number of times on stackoverflow and most people used

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to find unwanted dependencies and exclude them, e.g.

- [Maven SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896243/maven-slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings)
- [How to fix "SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings" at startup of Play 2.3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208943/how-to-fix-slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings-at-startup-of-pl)
- [SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024756/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings)

Comment: Hi, I deleted the jar slf4j in hbase lib folder,now its working.But I am getting a different error .
Error: org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative()V