# mocking method of class

Tags: java, junit, mocking, log4j

Exception while running junit

```
class JSONTool {
    private static MipLogger logger = MipLogger.getLogger(MIPJsonTool.class);

    public Object fetch(String url) {
        return invokeEndPoint(url, 2000, new HashMap<String, String>());
    }
}
```

i want to test this class and below is the test method

```
public void testFetchString() {
    JSONTool mipJsonTool = new JSONTool();
    JSONTool mipJsonTool1 = Mockito.spy(mipJsonTool);       
    Mockito.doReturn(new JSONObject()
            .put("status", 200))
            .when(mipJsonTool1)
            .fetch("http://localhost:5000/author");
    Object obj = mipJsonTool1.fetch("http://localhost:5000/author");
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

running junit gives below exception

> `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ReflectionUtil
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil`

Comment: Do you have log4j at your classpath?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700803/im-getting-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-logging-log4j-util-reflectionutil

Comment: @TobiSH i have log4j in classpath

Comment: But wrong version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting "NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ReflectionUtil"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700803/im-getting-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-logging-log4j-util-reflectionutil)

Comment: As @PolishCivil already mentioned. You might have the wrong version. Can you show us what you have on your classpath (incl. versions). I guess your problem has actually nothing to do with mocking a class.

Comment: compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.8.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.8.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-1.2-api', version: '2.8.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-jcl', version: '2.8.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-web', version: '2.8.2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NoClassDefFoundError** is an error that is thrown when the Java Runtime System tries to load the definition of a class, and that class definition is no longer available. The required class definition was present at compile time, but it was missing at runtime.

Check the logger configuration and the jar that you have used.

meanwhile you can provide the missing dependency for org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil

change the log4j version to 2.8.2 see if it helps

//edited version

I have created a project with below configuration to make the logger work

build.gradle

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    api 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.8.2'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:26.0-jre'


    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Create a **log4j2.properties** file under **src/main/resources** with below entries to show logs to console

```
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT


rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Below is the Java code that Invoke the logger (for testing I have put it inside a main method)

```
package GradleEclipseTestProject;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class GradleLog4jTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Testing log4j dependencies");
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
        logger.info("This is a sample logger");
    }

}
```

Comment: I have below dependecies for log4j
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.8.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.8.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-1.2-api', version: '2.8.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-jcl', version: '2.8.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-web', version: '2.8.2'

Comment: Are by any chance you are using SprinBoot ?

Comment: i am working on java gradle project not spring one, will it work different for spring project

Comment: @NareshKumar you can remove the other test and google guava dependencies it will work, that was the default addition.

Comment: @NareshKumar do you mind either accepting the answer or let me know if that's not what u wanted so that i can help you out with the problem ?

Comment: Thanks @hades for helping me on this.

Comment: you are welcome .. meanwhile do you mind upvoting the answer also as it will help me eating reputation. thanks