# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, using maven-shade-plugin to package

Tags: java, maven, jar, log4j

I use `mvn package` to package a uber-jar. The pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.zhihu</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-consumer</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>kafkadev</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <!-- Proper URL for Cloudera maven artifactory -->
      <id>cloudera</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>

  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- gson -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.12</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1-cdh6.2.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1-cdh6.2.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- runtime Hive -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1-cdh6.2.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-beeline</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1-cdh6.2.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1-cdh6.2.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-shims</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1-cdh6.2.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-serde</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1-cdh6.2.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-contrib</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1-cdh6.2.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                    <artifactSet>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>classworlds:classworlds</exclude>
                        <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                        <exclude>jmock:*</exclude>
                        <exclude>*:xml-apis</exclude>
                        <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </artifactSet>
            <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I run the jar it shows the Exception below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ReflectionUtil
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs.<clinit>(CommonClientConfigs.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.<clinit>(ConsumerConfig.java:461)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:652)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:632)
    at zhihu.ZhihuCommentConsumer.runMainLoop(ZhihuCommentConsumer.java:40)
    at zhihu.ZhihuCommentConsumer.main(ZhihuCommentConsumer.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: to fix CNFE, try adding log4j dependency in pom.xml.

Comment: @josepraveen  yes, I guess there is a conflict for log4j-api. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700803/im-getting-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-logging-log4j-util-reflectionutil